# How can I prepare WITH CLAUSE using Oracle .Net entity framework queries

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, common-table-expression

I'm trying to achieve the below query with entity query. How WITH Clause is implemented?

```
WITH EVENTS AS
(select * from EVENTS_ATCS WHERE ROWNUM <10)
select * from EVENTS A
LEFT JOIN ATCS_EVENT_MASTER B ON
(A.TYPEID = B.EventId)
AND
((A.BYTE1 >= B.GE_BYTE1 AND A.BYTE1 <= B.LE_BYTE1) OR (A.BYTE1 = B.E_BYTE1))
AND
((A.BYTE2 >= B.GE_BYTE2 AND A.BYTE2 <= B.LE_BYTE2) OR (A.BYTE2 = B.E_BYTE2))
AND
((A.BYTE3 >= B.GE_BYTE3 AND A.BYTE3 <= B.LE_BYTE3) OR (A.BYTE3 = B.E_BYTE3))
```

Comment: What is the real problem here? Why are you restricting the subquery with  ROWNUM? This seems like it would be a straightforward join query if only you had some proper filtering criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem, it is that you can't use the `WITH` factoring clause. If that's so, move the `EVENTS` CTE into the `FROM` clause:

```
select * 
from 
  (select * from EVENTS_ATCS WHERE ROWNUM <10) A           --> this is EVENTS
LEFT JOIN ATCS_EVENT_MASTER B ON (A.TYPEID = B.EventId)
AND ((A.BYTE1 >= B.GE_BYTE1 AND A.BYTE1 <= B.LE_BYTE1) OR (A.BYTE1 = B.E_BYTE1))
AND ((A.BYTE2 >= B.GE_BYTE2 AND A.BYTE2 <= B.LE_BYTE2) OR (A.BYTE2 = B.E_BYTE2))
AND ((A.BYTE3 >= B.GE_BYTE3 AND A.BYTE3 <= B.LE_BYTE3) OR (A.BYTE3 = B.E_BYTE3))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, How can i prepare join clause for this query in Entity Framework for Oracle?